# Any theory on whether good choices of $k$ depend on $N$ and $D$ in KNN classification?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour, manifold-learning

I am well aware that cross validation is a usual method for selecting hyperparameters. However, I am looking for theoretical guidance on how to pick $k$, the number of neighbors, for a $k$-nearest-neighbor classifier.

For example, one might imagine there exists a rule of the form $k^* \propto f(N, D)$ that advises how to scale $k$ as a function of the number of training data points, $N$, and the dimension of the data, $D$, which performs well under various assumptions, like smoothness, iid noise, etc.

Comment: I'm curious why this question was question downvoted, it's a fundamental question that one might ask about KNN.